# Word for hair growing from bald head

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Broadly, I am looking for a synonym for "stubble". It has to be gender-neutral so it won't look funny when it is used with males or females.

Context: The word is used when a bald person, who shaves their head regularly, stops shaving and lets their hair grow back.

Usage:

> - After a few days, there was a [___________] growing on his head.
> - "She was caressing her formerly bald head as it was slowly growing a [__________]."

I have looked at the word [fuzz](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fuzz) and I think it fits, but I'm looking for more options.

Comment: Fuzz would be a negative, laughing at the minimal growth, like peach fuzz on a teenager. Stubble is fine; so is Marine buzz cut or GI Joe.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know if I can use that in a gender-neutral context. I should have included it in the question.

Comment: Yes, use what you feel is best. Marine buzz cut or GI work for any baldness.

Comment: @YosefBaskin changed one example to 'she/her'

Comment: Stubble is thought of as masculine because it's usually seen in the form of unshaven beard, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: I'd call it *honorable mention*

Comment: Why doesn't "stubble" itself work?

Comment: Are they really *bald*–as in natural severe hair loss –if hair begins to grow back after two or three days? Aren't their heads just *shaved*? Many infants are born relatively bald but after a few months soft wisps of hair poke out, I'd never call that *stubble*.

Comment: ***Downy hair:***  covered with soft fine hair or feathers. light, soft, and fluffy.

Comment: Why can't you call it **hair**? "After a few days, hair could be seen growing on his head." And "She was caressing her formerly bald head as her hair slowly grew".

Comment: *After a few days, there was incipient hair on his head.*

Comment: "Stubble" is specific to hair (or crop stalks) that has been shaved (or cut), so seems correct in this context. It wouldn't be correct for an infant, or someone whose hair had fallen out and was now regrowing.

Comment: @WeatherVane or "new hair"

Comment: Like a brush, perhaps.

Comment: Velvet carries the sense 'something suggesting velvet', listed by [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/velvet). But in some contexts, confusion with more direct senses might occur.

Comment: What do women call the hair on their legs if they don't shave regularly? Bald heads are so strongly associated with men that there's not likely to be a neutral word for new hair there.